# labels overlapping in oxyplot c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I've created a plot in oxyplot that has a DateTimeAxis. My problem is that the labels are overlapping eachother which makes everything look really messy. Does anyone know if there is a way to solve this problem?

I've tried this solution: [Oxyplot: Prevent X-Axis label from overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733951/oxyplot-prevent-x-axis-label-from-overlapping) but it doesn't work. Instead the whole axis disappeared.

Comment: The `DateTime` here is long. Try to split the labels in the format `Date` + \n + `Time` . Thus Date & Time would get stacked below one another

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly. Maybe you should post it as an answer so I can give you your credit :)

Comment: Added my comment as answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DateTime` here is long. Try to split the labels in the format `Date` + \n + `Time` . Thus Date & Time would get stacked below one another.

I'm glad it worked out for u :)